# Estructura directorio test

Tags: python, flask, test, testing

Estoy diseñando la estructura para los test de una aplicación Flask. Tengo:

- test unitarios
- test de integración
- test de aceptación

Entonces, para los test unitarios y para los test de integración uso pytest y para los test de aceptación uso Behave.
La estructura de directios propuesta es:

```
- tests
  - unitarios
      test_uno.py
      test_dos.py
  - integración
      test...py
  - aceptación
      test...py
```

sería correcto este enfoque? ¿Existe algún mejor enfoque para realizar los test de integración (utilizando otro framework distinto a pytest)?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola desde mi experiencia, una forma simple de separar los diferentes tipos de test se puede conseguir con la siguiente estructura:

```
project/
│
├── my_app/
│   └── __init__.py
│
└── tests/
    |
    ├── unit/
    |   ├── __init__.py
    |   └── test_sum.py
    |
    └── integration/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_integration.py
```

Por lo que la respuesta a tu pregunta es sí, si que es una buena estructura la que habías pensado.

Un saludo y suerte con tu proyecto!

Puedes consultar esta web si necesitas mas información:
https://realpython.com/python-testing/#more-advanced-testing-scenarios